# Quiet Messages with arguments

Tags: message-coding

I have some global options that determine which messages are shown and which are not, e.g.

```
$MessagesShown = {Power::infy};
$MessagesNotShown = All;
```

Now the first line below will generate a message, while the second will not.

```
Quiet[1/0, Evaluate@$MessagesNotShown, Evaluate@$MessagesShown]
Quiet[0 Infinity, Evaluate@$MessagesNotShown, Evaluate@$MessagesShown]
```

This does not work however for messages that take an argument.
For instance,

```
Do[1/0,{5}]
Quiet[Do[1/0,{5}], Evaluate@$MessagesNotShown, Evaluate@$MessagesShown]
```

The first will display the `Power::infy` message 3 times and then the `General::stop` message, while the second only displays the `Power::infy` message 3 times.

Say we do want to see the `General::stop` message (and many other messages are generated as well so simply not using `Quiet` is not an option), we would change:

```
$MessagesShown={Power::infy,General::stop};
```

But now the code above gives the error message `Quiet::mgre`, saying that the message `General::stop` was not resolved to a list of messages of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language.

How do I do this? Is there a different syntax for messages with an argument?

Comment: The problem is that `General::stop` evaluates to a string. You will have to use Inactive or some type of hold gymnastics to prevent that.

Comment: @CarlWoll I see, is there any reason why messages with arguments evaluate to a string but messages without do not? I guess this means it is impossible to do with `$MessagesShown = {General::stop};`, or even with `$MessagesShown := {General::stop};`, it would really have to be something like `$MessagesShown = Inactive[Message][General,"stop"];`? That is unfortunate..

Comment: Basically, all General messages evaluate to a string, it's not just messages with arguments. Any non-General messages that don't refer to a General message also evaluate to a string. It is only non-General messages that refer to a General message that don't evaluate, e.g., Power::infy uses General::infy, and so it doesn't evaluate.

Comment: @CarlWoll I see, thanks. Then I think the simplest workaround is to define `Attributes[myQuiet]={HoldFirst}; myQuiet[expr_,Hold[quietMsgs_],Hold[shownMsgs_]]=Quiet[expr,quietMsgs,shownMsgs]` and then define e.g. `$MessagesShown=Hold[{Power::infy,General::stop}];`.